# How to perform .Select Linq Operation in a ObservableCollection<dynamic> in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, observablecollection

I'm having an `ObservableCollection<dynamic>`it contains a `ObservableCollection<MobileModel>`. Now I need to Select **Brand** Property from the `ObservableCollection<dynamic>`

The Class File is

```
public class Mobile
{
    private ObservableCollection<MobileModel> _mobileList;
    public ObservableCollection<MobileModel> MobileList
    {
        get { return _mobileList; }
        set { _mobileList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public void GetMobile()
    {
        List<MobileModel> mList = new List<MobileModel>();
        List<MobileModelInfo> modList = new List<MobileModelInfo>();
        MobileModel mob = new MobileModel();

        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Apple";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 6", Catagory = "Premium Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "IOS";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Samsung";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Android";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "MicroSoft";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "Lumina 9900", Catagory = "Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "Opera X220", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Windows";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Sony Ericssion";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Android";
        mList.Add(mob);

        MobileList = new ObservableCollection<MobileModel>(mList);

        SelectBrand(new ObservableCollection<dynamic>(MobileList.Cast<dynamic>()), "Brand");

    }


    public void SelectBrand(ObservableCollection<dynamic> Source, string propertyName)
    {
        // How to Create perform the Select Operation for the Property "Brand" as specified in the second parameter "propertyName"

        List<string> BrandList = new List<string>();

    }

}

public class MobileModel : Notify
{
    private string _brand = string.Empty;
    private ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> _model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>();
    private string _os = string.Empty;

    public string Brand
    {
        get { return _brand; }
        set { _brand = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { _model = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string OS
    {
        get { return _os; }
        set { _os = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public class MobileModelInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use dynamic? Why not change it to "ObservableCollection<MobileModel> Source"?

Comment: I need the function as an Universal format, it should be work for any collection. For an example I pasted only the MobileModel, I'm having lots of collections in my project. So, I need the Universal function to perform this operation. Kindly share your idea as per my requirement.

Comment: `dynamic` actually makes things harder here. `dynamic` provides runtime binding to type members, but it requires you know at compile-time what member you want. You'll need reflection to get at the property, and having the type as `dynamic` just makes that a bit harder. Do you have any specific reason for using `dynamic`? Or is that just a misguided attempt to implement this specific method?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the use of `dynamic` here. As I understand the question, you want to be able to essentially implement LINQ's `Select()`, except by specifying a property name instead of executing a selector delegate. Since the property name is not known at compile time, I don't see how `dynamic` would help.

So, ignoring `dynamic` for a moment, what you're asking is straightforward using reflection. For example:

```
class A
{
    public string P { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A[] rga =
        {
            new A { P = "One" },
            new A { P = "Two" },
            new A { P = "Three" },
        };

        foreach (string value in SelectProperty(rga, "P"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> SelectProperty<T>(IEnumerable<T> rga, string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

        foreach (T t in rga)
        {
            yield return (string)pi.GetValue(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in the above, because I am using the actual element type instead of `dynamic`, I don't have to wrap my collection in a whole new copy of the collection, and I have direct access to the type's reflected data (i.e. `PropertyInfo`) via compiler syntax instead of having to dig into the collection object actually passed to me.

You should be able to use something similar in your code, and you would call it by passing the `MobileList` object reference directly. E.g.:

```
List<string> brandList = SelectProperty(MobileList, "Brand").ToList();
```

That seems a lot better to me. :)

Comment: Not the code I posted, it doesn't. That's a complete, self-contained code example that I tested myself. You may have misapplied it. You should provide specific details regarding the difficulty you're having translating the above working example into something that works in your code. Be specific about any error messags you get, provide a full stack trace for any exceptions, and most importantly, add to your question a good [mcve] that reproduces the problem.